# Version Control with PHP

Tags: php, version-control

Currently I'm building a simple page for project hosting, and now I've got a question. Is there any implementation of GIT or HG (Mercurial) in PHP? - Yes I know about the command `system()`, but I'm doing the job on a hosting with few permissions and so I need something in bare PHP.

I already searched on the web, but I didn't find anything. =(

I hope there already exists something like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [glip](http://fimml.at/#glip) a try.  it looks like [git-php](http://zackb.org/git-php/index.php?p=git-php.git) might also do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, `glip` rocks, that's really very good for my purposes. I will try it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are PEAR packages for SVN and GIT :

- [**`VersionControl_Git`**](http://pear.php.net/package/VersionControl_Git)
- [**`VersionControl_SVN`**](http://pear.php.net/package/VersionControl_SVN)

But I don't remember having seen anything for Mercurial.